# NullInjectorError of feature store when testing component

Tags: angular, ngrx, testbed

I try to fix the test of `LoginComponent`. The error came when the feature store (notification) component was moved to a lazy-loaded module from `SharedModule`. I have no idea what can be wrong here. I tested many configurations of the testing component with ngrx. Also, moving back `NotificationModule` (with feature store) doesn't fix the bug due to the strong-refactor that was made.

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let store: MockStore<State>;


  beforeAll(() => {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 30000;
  });

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        SharedModule,
      ],
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore(),
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    store = TestBed.get(MockStore);

    spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));
```

LoginModule which is imported in AppModule.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    TranslateModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
  ],
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

Error:

```
Failed: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NotificationEffects -> Actions]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NotificationEffects -> Actions]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for Actions!
    error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'NotificationEffects', Function ] })
        at <Jasmine>
        at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:855:1)
        at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
        at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
        at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
        at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
        at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
        at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
        at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:30393:1)
        at _createClass (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:30470:1)
        at _createProviderInstance (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:30426:1)
    Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/login/login.component.ngrx.spec.ts:67:23)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that `NotificationEffects` requires an injectable `Actions` and the module does not know how to provide it. Looking into the provided code extraction it is impossible to know what is `Actions` and how should it be provided. You can start figuring it out by looking into `NotificationEffects` source code.

Comment: It helped, I noticed that `NotificationModule` is imported to other modules due to included components. I separated module it and tests started working.